# In VBA for Excel, why use activecell and activesheet when copy and pasting information derived on another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am following a YouTube tutorial on VBA for Excel. In one segment of the tutorial, the objective is to copy information from one sheet and paste it into specific cells on a different sheet within the same workbook. The correct piece of code for this process given in this part of the video is:

```
    Public Sub PopPandL()

Dim x As Integer
Dim sheet_title As String

For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1

Worksheets(x).Select
sheet_title = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("P&L").Select

Selection.Offset(x * 5 + 2, 0).Select
Selection.Value = sheet_title
Worksheets(x).Select

Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Copy
Sheets("P&L").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next x

End Sub
```

My question concerns the activecell and activesheet components of this code. To experiment, when I try to use:

```
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste
```

as an alternative, I get an error saying that the object does not support this property or method. Why is this?

Comment: Sadly YouTube videos aren't guaranteed to be the best... see for example [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I think it's because there is no such `Paste` method for `Range` object, while there is [`PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial)

Comment: This code is full of things that are considered bad practices in Excel VBA.  I would avoid this tutorial in the future.

Comment: Sidge, do not forget to accept answers give by the community. Take the site's tour if you are unfamiliar with the mechanics. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bigben said - YouTube videos aren't guaranteed.  Neither are answers on here or any other forum.

As @HTH said (sorry, didn't quite understand what he was getting at until I tried it).
[Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste) is a Worksheet method and you're trying to use it on a range on a sheet.
`ActiveSheet.Paste` will paste to the selected cell on the active sheet.

Saying all that, I think this is the code you're after:

```
Public Sub PopPandL()
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim PasteToRow As Long

    For Each wrksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrksht.Name <> "P&L" Then
            PasteToRow = wrksht.Index * 5 + 2
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L").Cells(PasteToRow, 1) = wrksht.Name
            wrksht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
                Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L").Cells(PasteToRow + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next wrksht
End Sub
```

On a side note I wouldn't use `CurrentRegion` either as that can return incorrect results - either use a method to find the last cell on the sheet containing data (if that's what you need) or maybe put your data in a table and use `ListObjects`.

Comment: Good point - didn't spot that. I'm guessing the last sheet is the P&L one so have updated code to miss that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I simulated for you. As it is said in the comment, it is highly recommended not to use `Selection` [or `Activate` as it is from the comment below]:

**Updated Code** without Activate

```
'Copy from A1 of the Active Sheet
Dim mySelection As Range
Set mySelection = Range("A1")
mySelection.CurrentRegion.Copy

'Goto Sheet P&L
Sheets("P&L").Activate

'Convert the current R
'Goto the Last Line of the Sheet P&L (That's the Offsite want to do)
Dim PLLastRow As Range
Set PLLastRow = Sheets("P&L").Range(Selection.Address).Offset(1, 0)

'Paste the Clipboard on that last Sheet
PLLastRow.PasteSpecial
```

**Old Code** below:
    'Copy from A1 of the Active Sheet
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Copy

```
'Goto Sheet P&L
Sheets("P&L").Activate

'Convert the current R
'Goto the Last Line of the Sheet P&L (That's the Offsite want to do)
Dim PLLastRow As Range
Set PLLastRow = Sheets("P&L").Range(Selection.Address).Offset(1, 0)

'Activate the Cell
PLLastRow.Activate

'Paste the Clipboard on that last Sheet
PLLastRow.PasteSpecial  '<--- Use PasteSpecial as Paste doesn't exist
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: it is highly recommended not to use `Activate`/`Active...`, too, for mostly the same reasons of "forbidding" `Select`/`Selection`. You could edit your post to reflect this

Comment: Actually, I prefer `Activate` because it doesn't require that the cell or the sheet receives the focus for it to work. Surely you could give me a better option then to replace `Activate`?

Comment: Give [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read.

Comment: of course: use direct object reference. like, for instance `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy`

Comment: So if I understand it well, once we assign the range to a Range Variable then we do not need to Activate it anymore?

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, very interesting article. Just updated my answer based on your suggestions

Comment: How to activate the Sheet without `Sheets("P&L").Activate`?

Comment: _"So if I understand it well, once we assign the range to a Range Variable then we do not need to Activate it anymore?"_: well it suffices referencing the object without assigning it (as my example `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy`)

Comment: _"How to activate the Sheet without Sheets("P&L").Activate? "_ the point is you don't really need to actvate it!.

Comment: But what* shall we use to change the ActiveSheet to be a certain sheet of the Workbook without using `Sheetxx.Select` or `Sheetxx.Activate`?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina, you don't need to `Activate` a sheet unless in very specific and quite few cases, and this is not one of them. Whatever sheet child object you need to use , just use full reference up to sheet object, like, for instance `Set PLLastRow = Sheets("P&L").Range("A1")`, which references cell A1 in sheet "P&L" without any need to activate it

Comment: Then I am with you. I still can use it when I need to see the Sheet focused, but if it is just a background operations, then there is not need at all to activate any cell or sheet. Isn't it?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina,  It is! Which reduces the activating of a sheet to a very very few cases

Comment: Just add my tuppence in here. As an example of not activating a sheet - if you're on Sheet3 the code `Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy Sheet2.Range("A2")` will still copy the contents of A1 in Sheet1 to A2 in Sheet2 (using sheet codenames for brevity).  No activating or selecting needed.